# How to process CoreData Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift4.2

I've the following entities and relationships:

[image: click here to see the CoreData image]

I want to do a calculation: 
I want to get the amounts of all receipts of a specific category and sum them.

For example: 
I want to retrieve the total amount of all receipts of category "Restaurants"

How can I do that using Swift 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example simply fetch an array of dictionaries, get the values and sum them up

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Receipt")
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
request.propertiesToFetch = ["amount"]
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "toCategory.category == %@", "Restaurant")
do {
    let objects = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as! [[String:Int]]
    let sum = objects.compactMap{$0["amount"]}.reduce(0, +)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: That shows me many errors: Line 2 : Expected declaration.  Line 5: Use of unresolved identifier 'managedObjectContext'; did you mean 'NSManagedObjectContext'?   Line 6: Type 'StatisticsViewController' has no member 'objects'

Comment: Of course you have to import CoreData, `managedObjectContext` is the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance of the Core Data stack, the `try` line is supposed to be wrapped in a `do - catch` block and the entire code must be inside of a method..

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in App development :(. I couldn't get your explanation. Can you explain more in code, please? I don't know how to use do - catch

Comment: it still gives me this error: Use of unresolved identifier 'managedObjectContext'; did you mean 'NSManagedObjectContext'? I've imported CoreData.

Comment: As I said you need the reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance of the Core Data stack. It’s usually in AppDelegate but it can be anywhere.

Comment: Ok found it. but I got this error: Value of type '[[String : Int]]' has no member 'values'